# GLSL texture mapping and coloring in the same shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to write a GLSL Fragment Shader that can do texture mapping and vertex coloring. Is it possible to do both in the one shader?

At the moment, I can do this:

`gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].st);`

Which causes textured verts to be drawn, but not colored verts.
(which looks like this: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=124eb69)

I can also do this:

`gl_FragColor = gl_Color;`

Which causes colored verts to be drawn but not textured verts.
(Which looks like this: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=5bcd838)

If I do this:

`gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].st) * gl_Color;` (which looks like the first code snippet)

Only textured verts get drawn... which is my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "get drawn"? What results are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: I mean they don't show up on the screen. What I expect to see is the textured and non-textured verts to all show up, in the last code snippet.

Comment: *"Only textured verts get drawn"* - Well, of course, since you're multiplying the colors and everything in the texture is **black** (color value 0), except for the letters. As we learn from school, `0 * 0 = 0`. It's not that they are magically *"not drawn"*, they're just colored **black**.

Comment: No what I mean is, see there's a grey box supposed to be behind the text, and a white box in the center. Which don't get drawn when I use the first snippet.

Comment: @TomTetlaw When using the first snippet, you're not using colors at all, so this is out of the question anyway. When using the one with the multiplication, you are multiplying the color from the per-vertex coloring (grey for a fragment inside the grey box) with the color of the texture, which is just **black** nearly everywhere and **black** * **grey** = **black**, that easy. What are you expecting, a sum of the two colors? If yes, then, well, change the `*` into a `+` and look what happens.

Comment: So whenever I am drawing verticies without a texture, I should glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0) before-hand so that the equasion will be **white * grey = grey** ?

Comment: @TomTetlaw No, when texturing, binding 0 as texture will cause rubbish to happen (probably an all-black default texture or whatever your hardware thinks best). When drawing vertices without texturing, then, well, use a shader that doesn't do texturing. It might also work to use an all-white dummy-texture but this is more of a hack than an actual solution, but ok, if almost anything is textured it might be an easier solution than using an extra shader. But still, binding 0 as texture and then doing texturing is definitely wrong.

Comment: That did it. Binding a white colored texture fixed my problem. Thank you all for your help. Just a quick question - which should I accept as the answer for this question, since it was a comment that was the answer?

Comment: @TomTetlaw *Nicol*'s as his is the actual correct answer, given the fundamental understanding problems present in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I expect to see is the textured and non-textured verts to all show up, in the last code snippet.

You shouldn't expect that.

There's no such thing as a "textured vert" or a "non-textured vert". There is only a *color*, whatever that color may be. That's the whole point of shaders: to use arbitrary code to compute a color however you want.

You are computing the color by multiplying the result of a texture fetch with a per-vertex interpolated color. The result will be a *combination* of the two colors. Namely, the product of them. Therefore, the resultant color will look somewhat like the original texture.

Comment: I don't think I'm explaining it correctly. I've uploaded some photos of what it looks like with each code snippet, hopefully now I can explain it better. I want a fragment shader that can work for both snippet 1, and snippet 2, but I can't get it to work like that.

Comment: @TomTetlaw: What do you mean by "both"? You can only output one color per fragment (unless you're drawing to multiple buffers). Do you mean that you want a way to switch between the two? What *mathematically* are you looking for?